# How to remove/avoid a particular string in SQL output

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the SQL Query:

```
select '"'|| trim(COLUMN1) ||'"|"'|| trim(COLUMN2) ||'"|"'|| trim(COLUMN3) ||'"'
from TABLE1 where ....
```

The output I get is:

```
"DATA1"|""|"DATA3"

"DATA4"|""|"DATA6"
```

But, I want it to display the output like below:

```
"DATA1"||"DATA3"

"DATA4"||"DATA6"
```

That means, if there is some null value of a particular column, it must not display "". I hope you all got it.
Please help me achieving this, as I am automating this process where in the output file goes directly to the destination application (i.e. I won't be able to modify it manually).
Thanks!

Comment: You should clarify whether you want to apply the suppression to just `COLUMN2` or to all columns in the projection. That is, can `COLUMN1` or `COLUMN3` be null? If so, how would the output look? The solutions will be subtly different.

Comment: Also, is this a solution for generating a pipe-separated file (i.e. CSV with a different delimiter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NVL2( value, value_if_not_null, value_if_null )`:

```
SELECT NVL2( COLUMN1, '"' || TRIM( COLUMN1 ) || '"', NULL )
       || '|' || NVL2( COLUMN2, '"' || TRIM( COLUMN2 ) || '"', NULL )
       || '|' || NVL2( COLUMN3, '"' || TRIM( COLUMN3 ) || '"', NULL )
FROM   table1
WHERE  -- ...
```

Or `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL THEN '"' || TRIM( COLUMN1 ) || '"' END
       || '|' || CASE WHEN COLUMN2 IS NOT NULL THEN '"' || TRIM( COLUMN2 ) || '"' END
       || '|' || CASE WHEN COLUMN3 IS NOT NULL THEN '"' || TRIM( COLUMN3 ) || '"' END
FROM   table1
WHERE  -- ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` to avoid printing anything if the column is `null`

```
select  '"'|| trim(COLUMN1) || '"|' ||
        case when COLUMN2 is null then '' else '"' || trim(COLUMN2) || '"' end
       || '|"' || trim(COLUMN3) ||'"'
from TABLE1 where ....
```

Answer (score 0):

replace Function

```
select replace('"'|| trim(COLUMN1) ||'"|"'|| trim(COLUMN2) ||'"|"'|| trim(COLUMN3) ||'"', '""','')
from TABLE1 where ....
```

Comment: What happens if the column values contain the string `""`?

Comment: Not really. If the `COLUMN2` value is `You can create a string using "" double quotes` then your output would be `You can create a string using  double quotes` which changes the data the OP is trying to display.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
REPLACE(String, '""', '')

select REPLACE('"'|| trim(COLUMN1) ||'"|"'|| trim(COLUMN2) ||'"|"'|| trim(COLUMN3) ||'"', '""', '') from TABLE1 where ....
```

Comment: What happens if the column values contain the string `""`?